# How to redirect page with query string for HTACCESS?

Tags: php, apache, query-string, redirect

How would I go about redirecting the below URL with query string. The new URLS will include `"page = page name"` as the first parameter as a result. The values of all of the other parameters will vary.

1)

**OLD**

> `https://example.com/index.php?LOANAMOUNT=350%2C000.00&DOWNPAYMENT=20.000+&DOWNPAYMENT_TYPE=Percent&TERM=30&TERM_UNITS=Years&INTERESTRATE=5.700+&COMPUTE=COMPUTE&CALCULATORID=HF02&TEMPLATE_ID=www.abc.com_1&PostBack=true#results`

**NEW**

> `https://example.com/index.php?page=monthly-payment&LOANAMOUNT=350%2C000.00&DOWNPAYMENT=20.000+&DOWNPAYMENT_TYPE=Percent&TERM=30&TERM_UNITS=Years&INTERESTRATE=5.700+&COMPUTE=COMPUTE&CALCULATORID=HF02&TEMPLATE_ID=www.abc.com_1&PostBack=true#results`

2)

**OLD**

> `https://example.com/index.php?MAXPAYMENTAMOUNT=2%2C100.00&INSURANCE=80.00&PROPERTYTAX=1.250+&PROPERTYTAX_TYPE=Percent&ASSOCIATIONDUES=0.00&DOWNPAYMENT=10.000+&DOWNPAYMENT_TYPE=Percent&TERM=30&TERM_UNITS=Years&INTERESTRATE=5.700+&INCOMETAXRATE=25.000+&COMPUTE=COMPUTE&CALCULATORID=HF09&TEMPLATE_ID=www.abc.com_1&PostBack=true#results`

**NEW**

> `https://example.com/index.php?page=how-much-can-i-afford&MAXPAYMENTAMOUNT=2%2C100.00&INSURANCE=80.00&PROPERTYTAX=1.250+&PROPERTYTAX_TYPE=Percent&ASSOCIATIONDUES=0.00&DOWNPAYMENT=10.000+&DOWNPAYMENT_TYPE=Percent&TERM=30&TERM_UNITS=Years&INTERESTRATE=5.700+&INCOMETAXRATE=25.000+&COMPUTE=COMPUTE&CALCULATORID=HF09&TEMPLATE_ID=www.abc.com_1&PostBack=true#results`

3)

**OLD**

> `https://example.com/index.php?ORIGINALLOANAMOUNT=400%2C000.00&ORIGINALTERM=30&ORIGINALTERM_UNITS=Years&LOANSTARTMONTH=7&LOANSTARTYEAR=2018&CURRENTRATE=5.700+&CASHOUT=5%2C000.00&NEWRATE=5.250+&POINTS=1.000+&OTHERFEES=1%2C500.00&NEWTERM=30&NEWTERM_UNITS=Years&TAXRATE=28.000+&RATEOFRETURN=2.300+&BALLOONTERM=15&BALLOONTERM_UNITS=Years&COMPUTE=COMPUTE&CURRENTCOMPOUNDING=6&NEWCOMPOUNDING=6&CALCULATORID=HF01&TEMPLATE_ID=www.abc.com_1&PostBack=true#results`

**NEW**

> `https://example.com/index.php?page=should-i-refinance&ORIGINALLOANAMOUNT=400%2C000.00&ORIGINALTERM=30&ORIGINALTERM_UNITS=Years&LOANSTARTMONTH=7&LOANSTARTYEAR=2018&CURRENTRATE=5.700+&CASHOUT=5%2C000.00&NEWRATE=5.250+&POINTS=1.000+&OTHERFEES=1%2C500.00&NEWTERM=30&NEWTERM_UNITS=Years&TAXRATE=28.000+&RATEOFRETURN=2.300+&BALLOONTERM=15&BALLOONTERM_UNITS=Years&COMPUTE=COMPUTE&CURRENTCOMPOUNDING=6&NEWCOMPOUNDING=6&CALCULATORID=HF01&TEMPLATE_ID=www.abc.com_1&PostBack=true#results`

Comment: I am using a 3rd party script that redirects the user with the additional parameters shown in the "new" URL. The script is built so that it will append parameters from user input to the file path without the "page" parameter. This is a problem for me because the CMS I use looks for the parameter "page" to show a page. If I manually type out the URL, I will get the results I expect. Thank you for your input, Dinesh.

Anyone else know the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

- Create an .htaccess file on your web server

**Redirecting a URL**

Using Redirect in an .htaccess file enables you to redirect users from an old page to a new page without having to keep the old page. For example, if you use index.html as your index file and then later rename index.html to home.html, you could set up a redirect to send users from index.html to home.html.

For example:

**Redirect to a local site file**

```
Redirect /path/to/old/file/old.html /path/to/new/file/new.html
```

**Redirect to an external site file**

```
Redirect /path/to/old/file/old.html http://www.example.com/new/file/new.html
```

**Examples of redirects**

**Redirect from an index.html file to a different directory**

```
Redirect /index.html /new/
```

**Redirect from index.html to default.html**

```
Redirect /index.html /default.html
```

**Redirect a local /private directory to another site's private directory**

```
Redirect /private/ http://www.example.com/private/
```

Refer:https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-